# Linux: Output N Number of lines, starting from the End of a File

Tags: linux

I want to output the *last* 3000 lines of a log file.

In other words: I do not want to print the *first* 3000 lines of the log file: Instead I want to print the *last* 3000 lines of a log file.

I know `tac`prints out to the terminal screen the log file in its entirety in reverse order.  But I do not want to print out the entire file. I looked at the available options and it appears that `tac` cannot print out a certain number of lines.

Ultimately: I do not care if the last 3000 lines are printed out in ascending order or descending order: I just want to be able to see the last 3000 lines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use:

```
tail -n 3000 | tac
```

if you want reverse order, otherwise, just

```
tail -n 3000
```